# Is it right the word "the" is an article that functions as both an adjective and an adverb?

Tags: grammar

Those especially Indian or learners form countries of East Asia want to create something a new in language. It is so hard to make them satisfied ....

I know any item precedes a noun can function as adjective.

For example they say:

In short, the word "the" is an article that functions as both an adjective and an adverb, depending on how it's being used.  Moreover, they say : "the" is an adverb before superlative adjectives  ?

[https://blog.prepscholar.com/what-part-of-speech-is-the-word-the#:~:text=In%20short%2C%20the%20word%20%22the,article%20in%20the%20English%20language](https://blog.prepscholar.com/what-part-of-speech-is-the-word-the#:%7E:text=In%20short%2C%20the%20word%20%22the,article%20in%20the%20English%20language).

I searched all books of Google and I never found such result !

I can say it acts as a determiner not more.

The main function of adverbs is to modify the verbs.
My question to those " Can THE modify the verbs?"

If so then it perhaps acts as adverb.

Comment: An adverb doesn't necessarily need to modify verbs to be an adverb. For example: "very".

Comment: OK, ( very ) the intensifier does not modify the verb. Can " the" replace it always or does the same function of very ? When we say about something " very useful  \ very happy" = to far extent useful \ happy .. The better informed you are, the happier you'll be with your new vehicle.   Mention to me one book tells  the = adverb

Comment: Mention to me one book tells the = adverb either Oxford or Cambridge Not Indian books

Comment: It is discussed [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/301872/is-the-an-adverb-or-an-adjective). Your "...it acts as a determiner, not more" appears to be correct. Even the most respected dictionaries seem slow to adopt the findings of today's grammarians.

Comment: "The" belongs solely to the category (part of speech) determinative. It almost always functions as a determiner, but it can also be a modifier, either of superlatives, as in _He's now **the fattest** he's ever been_, or of adjectives such as in _The more conditions bite, **the worse** the violence becomes_.